# PHP Riddle. The function of the pyramid

Tags: php

I have a riddle for you.

I need a function that displays the number of pyramid structures.

Example: echo getNumber(7)

Output: 12345677654321

In this case, do not use  outside functions and operators.

From the mathematical symbols use only addition. **Dont use for/while/implode/range/count.**

Maximum use of one condition.

Good luck!

Comment: recursion?  getNumber can recursively call itself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your assignment IS RECURSION.

Take a look, and good luck.

I do not want to give you the answer as others take shame upon that.  But here is an example of how you would get 7654321 with a recursive function.

```
function getNumbers(int val) {

if val != 0
{
    echo val;
    val = val -1;
    getNumbers(val)
}


}
```

Comment: "The answer to your assignment" **Zing!**